# Underscore.js re-structure an object based on values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I'm using underscore.js, of course any solution is fine, but I have an object that looks like this:

```
{ '4f871d4967e04': 
   [ { _id: 4f871d4adaf6fa492f000001,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '300',
       height: 300,
       group: '4f871d4967e04' },
     { _id: 4f871d4adaf6fa492f000004,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '150',
       height: 150,
       group: '4f871d4967e04' },
     { _id: 4f871d4bdaf6fa492f000007,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '100',
       height: 100,
       group: '4f871d4967e04' },
     { _id: 4f871d4bdaf6fa492f00000a,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '75',
       height: 75,
       group: '4f871d4967e04' } ],
  '4f871d51200de': 
   [ { _id: 4f871d51daf6faf42e000001,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '300',
       height: 300,
       group: '4f871d51200de' },
     { _id: 4f871d52daf6faf42e000004,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '150',
       height: 150,
       group: '4f871d51200de' },
     { _id: 4f871d53daf6faf42e000007,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '100',
       height: 100,
       group: '4f871d51200de' },
     { _id: 4f871d53daf6faf42e00000a,
       product_id: 4f871d43daf6fa4e2f000002,
       width: '75',
       height: 75,
       group: '4f871d51200de' } ] }
```

I'd like to turn it to this:

```
{"4f871d4967e04" : {
 "300" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "150" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "100" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "75" : {
    _id : '',
  }
}, "4f871d4967e04" : {
 "300" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "150" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "100" : {
    _id : '',
  }
 "75" : {
    _id : '',
  }
}
```

This way I can iterate through each "group" and simply use `this["300"]` to get the size that I want.  I'm iterating through this in Handlebar's templates, so I'm limited to what conditions I can check for.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious plain-jane JavaScript approach would probably be the quickest:

```
var want = { };
var k, i, o;
for(k in data) {
    want[k] = { };
    for(i = 0; i < data[k].length; ++i) {
        o = data[k][i];
        want[k][o.width] = o;
    }
}
```

Simply loop through the main object (`data`) key by key and use an inner loop to rearrange the arrays into width→object mapping tables.

Anything you come up with will probably be that nested loop in disguise. The Underscore version would look something like this:

```
var want = _(data).reduce(function(outer, v, k) {
    outer[k] = _(v).reduce(function(inner, o) {
        inner[o.width] = o;
        return inner;
    }, { });
    return outer;
}, { });
```

That's pretty much the original nested `for` loop set up with [`reduce`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reduce) in place of the loops. You're pretty much limited to using `reduce` here as most Underscore functions really want to turn everything into an array. You could use [`each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each):

```
var want = { };
_(data).each(function(v, k) {
    var inner = { };
    _(v).each(function(o) {
        inner[o.width] = o;
    });
    want[k] = inner;
});
```

But that's the same as the `reduce` approach with temporary variables. You could probably come up with other approaches but they'll probably just be more variations on this theme.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ffcUC/2/

---

If you want to send your data into a Handlebars template like:

```
{{#each images}}<img src="../{{this.300._id}}" />{{/each}}
```

Then you only want the values from what the above produces. But in this case, you can adjust your loops to save some work:

```
var want = [ ];
var k, i, o;
for(k in data) {
    o = { };
    for(i = 0; i < data[k].length; ++i) {
        o[data[k][i].width] = data[k][i];
    }
    want.push(o);
}
return want;
```

Or switch to `reduce` inside a [`map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map):

```
var index_by_height = function(o) {
    return _(o).reduce(function(memo, i) {
        memo[i.height] = i;
        return memo;
    }, { });
};
return _.chain(data)
        .values()
        .map(index_by_height)
        .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tsx7z/

Comment: Awesome - Thank you.  Although, it doesn't seem to work with Handlebars, herm.

Comment: @dave: What are you trying to do on the Handlebars side?

Comment: Something like this `{{#each images}}<img src="../{{this.300._id}}" />{{/each}}` or I could do `{{#each images}}<img src="../{{this.75._id}}" />{{/each}}`, etc.  Basically being able to select which size from each "set" to show.

Comment: @dave: In that case you don't want the whole object, you just want the values as an array: `images: _(reduce_reduce()).values()` and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ffcUC/3/